# MacOS finder low fps

Tags: macos, finder

How to enable my MacOS smoother? I have a feeling that FPS in macos is really low, I have checked that with iStats Menu app and I have from 4 to 30 FPS which is really bad result and it can be felt when you are work on this machine. Is there any way to increase FPS or refresh rate?
I have MacBook Pro 15" from 2018 2.6GHz + 16GB RAM.

[image]

Comment: Is this about CPU/System Performance or about FPS? What kind of applications are you running, what does the CPU graph in Activity Monitor Show?

Comment: About FPS, on VS Code I have 60FPS but on Finder I have 2-10 FPS I depends what I am doing. It is really annoying and I want to lock this FPS to 60 and turn off that jumping from 0 to 60

Comment: Why does FPS in Finder matter?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly refresh rate & FPS are not even slightly related. Refresh rate is a constant (the number of times a second your physical screen changes content), FPS is a variable.
Finder simply doesn't need high FPS all the time. Why on earth would you need 'gaming-level' response just to look at files on a screen?

Also, Finder FPS is responsive to your actions.
If you **do** start dragging things around quickly, the FPS goes up to compensate. If you quickly dash back to iStat to check, you'll see the figure is higher, then will rapidly drop away again.

If VSCode is constantly ramping the FPS up to 60, then it is just badly coded & wasting energy. Even YouTube will only lift the FPS to the rate of the video currently playing. Any more would just be slightly heating up your room, nothing else.

From my recent background running support for an online gaming structure for the past decade, "*bigger better faster more*" culture makes this FPS misinformation a constant bane to support staff. People just have the wrong idea of what it's for & how it works. There has been for the past few years an 'internet meme' of massive fps being "better" for gaming. This, so people think, is "better" even if your game is running 120 FPS yet your screen can only refresh at 60.
This is, if you think about it carefully, patently absurd.

Comment: It looks weird because I have iMac as my second machine and I have plugged there 144Hz extended monitor and finder looks great there but on MacBook I see this flickering and switching

Comment: What you are perceiving then is the difference the refresh rate makes, not FPS. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I know what is FPS and how it works but I just cannot accept this that I have 60Hz screen and when I change my desktops I see this flickering. I see this moment when FPS jumps from 2 to 30FPS that's what my question is about

Comment: Please read my answer more carefully. FPS & refresh rate are not connected, not at all, not in the slightest.

Comment: So is there any way to increase refresh rate? In my display options I can't see this even with Option pressed

Comment: VSCode runs 60FPS when I am scrolling in other cases it's 0

Comment: There is no way to increase refresh rate beyond what your screen is capable of. As I already said in my answer, refresh rate is a constant. Yet again, FPS has **absolutely nothing to do with refresh rate**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118412/discussion-between-freestyle09-and-tetsujin).